# Why should IO as Byte be avoided in Java

Tags: java, stream

`CopyBytes` seems like a normal program, but it actually represents a kind of low-level I/O that you should avoid. It has been mentioned that there are streams for characters ,objects etc that should be preferred although all are built on the `bytestream` itself. What is a reason behind this, has it anything to do with security manager and performance related issues?

source : [oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works, but is very inefficient: it needs 2 method calls for every single byte it copies.

Instead, you should use a buffer (of several thousand bytes, the best size varies by what exactly you read and other conditions) and read/write the entire buffer (or as much as possible) with every method call.

Comment: More to the point, though, you should not be messing with byte streams at all, if you need to read a text file. At least that's what it says right after the sentence quoted in the question.

Comment: @Joachim but it also says that all streams are built on bytestreams itself ., does that mean that this inefficiency is inherited in all the streams then??

Comment: @sand1988: there are other methods to read a lot of bytes in one method call.

Comment: @Thilo: well, except if you *only* want to copy data without handling it in any other way, then byte streams work just fine.

Answer (score 4):

What Oracle is actually saying, is "Please do not reimplement the wheel!".

You should almost never *need* regular Byte streams:

- Are you parsing text? Use a Character stream, which understand text encoding issues.
- Are you parsing XML? Use SAX or some other library.
- Are you parsing images? Use ImageIO class.
- Are you copying things from A to B? Use apache commons-io FileUtils.

There are very few situations where you will actually need to use the bytestream.

Comment: +1 for all these examples. Especially commons-io is something that everyone should know about.

Answer (score 3):

From the text you quoted:

> CopyBytes seems like a normal program, but it actually represents a kind of low-level I/O that you should avoid. **Since xanadu.txt contains character data, the best approach is to use character streams**, as discussed in the next section. There are also streams for more complicated data types. Byte streams should only be used for the most primitive I/O.

Usually, you don't want to work with bytes directly. There are higher-level APIs, for example to read text (i.e. character data that has to be decoded from bytes).

Comment: I have to read a file which I do not know of what kind it is? . I have split it into pieces and you know the kind of file will keep on varying so should I use a byte stream for this?

Comment: What do you want to do with the file? For simple "read file into memory", take a look at Commons-IO.

Comment: yes i want to do the same thing. Although re-usability is an important aspect of Software engineering, but for the purpose of a better understanding at this point I would like to  do it with self made functions. So what is the best possible way of doing it without using Commons-IO. "I want to read a file , split it and store back into pieces".

Comment: @sand1988: again, it depends on what you want to do with the pieces: if all you want to do is re-construct the original one at some point, then simply use bytes. If you want each separate part to be readable (for example you want to split at word boundaries), then you'll need to use something else (`Reader`/`Writer` in the case of text).